# Python writing dictionary to csv and read dictionary from csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I'm using pandas to handle data frames. There's one data frame I create which its rows are as follows: `[id, vector]` 
Where id is of type string and vector is of type dictionary.

Now when I write it to a csv file The row looks like this (in the csv file):

```
25377bc2-d3b6-4699-a466-6b9f544e8ba3    {u'sport>sports event>world championship': 0.5058, u'sport>sports event': 0.7032, u'sport>soccer': 0.6377, u'lifestyle and leisure>game': 0.4673, u'sport>sports event>world cup': 0.6614, u'sport>sports event>international tournament': 0.454, u'sport>sports event>national tournament': 0.541, u'sport': 0.9069, u'sport>sports organisations>international federation': 0.5046, u'sport>sports organisations': 0.6982}
```

I've tried to read it back from csv into pandas data frame, but when I look at the type of the vector that once was a `dict` it is now of `<type 'str'>`

I know I can solve it with pickle and save that pandas data frame into a pickle file. But is there a way to read the csv correctly (where the vector in it is of type dictionary)

Comment: Is possible save to `json` ?

Comment: Yes. I'll be glad to also see a json solution and your recommendation will be gladly heard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `json` what is better structure as `csv` for save `dicts`.

For write use [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) and for read [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) with parameter `orient='records'`, thanks [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46628403/python-writing-dictionary-to-csv-and-read-dictionary-from-csv/46628458#comment80206947_46628458) for comment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vector':[{'a':1, 'b':3}, {'a':4, 'b':6}], 'ID':[2,3]})
print (df)
   ID            vector
0   2  {'b': 3, 'a': 1}
1   3  {'b': 6, 'a': 4}

df.to_json('file.json', orient='records')
   ID            vector
0   2  {'b': 3, 'a': 1}
1   3  {'b': 6, 'a': 4}

df = pd.read_json('file.json', orient='records')
print (df)

print (df.applymap(type))
              ID          vector
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'dict'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'dict'>
```

EDIT1:

If is necessary same order of columns, index values use:

```
df.to_json('file.json', orient='split')

df = pd.read_json('file.json', orient='split')
```

Comment: I think `orient='records'` might be more appropriate as the resulting `json` has only the `id` and `vector` keys.

Comment: @EranMoshe - For me it working nice, there is some problem with real data with my solution?

Comment: I've checked it both with orient='records' and without, and it worked both times. Thanks.

Comment: I check it too and I think if check json files there is differnent structure. Solution with orient=records has advantage - better readable json and lower size of file.